# git (v1.9.1) clone not auto tracking branch

Tags: git, github, tracking, git-clone

I have few github repositories. When I clone a certain repository, the subsequent checkout of branches are auto-tracked. But it does not happen for few other repos.

My git version

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/wq$ git --version
git version 1.9.1
```

Auto-tracking git clone

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env$ git clone git@github.com:XYZ/lb.git lb
Cloning into 'lb'...
remote: Counting objects: 6433, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 6433 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 6431
Receiving objects: 100% (6433/6433), 7.24 MiB | 10.79 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4636/4636), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
root@e7440:~/dev_env$ cd lb
```

Checking out develop branch

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/lb$ git checkout develop
Branch develop set up to track remote branch develop from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'develop'
```

The checked out branch 'develop' auto tracked

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/lb$ git branch
* develop
  master
```

Remote branches on lb repo

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/lb$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/master
  origin/production
  origin/stage
```

Another repository in the same account does not auto-track when branches are checked out

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env$ git clone --no-single-branch git@github.com:XYZ/wq.git wq
Cloning into 'wq'...
remote: Counting objects: 13552, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3397/3397), done.
remote: Total 13552 (delta 348), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 10155
Receiving objects: 100% (13552/13552), 15.95 MiB | 10.83 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5481/5481), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
root@e7440:~/dev_env/lb$ cd wq
```

Checking out develop branch on 'wq' repo

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/wq$ git checkout develop
root@e7440:~/dev_env/wq$ git branch
* master
```

All remote branches of the 'wq' repository

```
root@e7440:~/dev_env/wq$ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/feature-gulpversion
  origin/feature-lb-groups
  origin/feature-maps
  origin/feature-pic
  origin/feature-redesign
  origin/feature-timerz
  origin/master
  origin/production
  origin/stage
```

I am not sure why this is happening. How can I make sure that the remote branches are auto-tracked when the local branch name matches the remote branch name.

The .git/config for the affected repo

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:XYZ/wq.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Output of git flow init commands

```
$:~/dev_env$ git clone --no-single-branch git@github.com:XYZ/wq.git wq
Cloning into 'wq'...
remote: Counting objects: 13567, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3412/3412), done.
remote: Total 13567 (delta 353), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 10155
Receiving objects: 100% (13567/13567), 16.05 MiB | 559.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5486/5486), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$:~/dev_env$ cd wq
$:~/dev_env/wq$ git flow init -f

Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases?
   - master
Branch name for production releases: [master] production

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?
   - master
Branch name for "next release" development: [master] develop
Fatal: Local branch 'develop' does not exist.
```

It exits out of git flow with error.

Realized one thing, that this branch is a forked branch from another branch

Comment: maybe you could look through the .git dir, and look to see if there is anything in the config that would prevent this from happening

Comment: As mentioned above it looks like there is something in your config file. can you please paste it (the section regarding the given branch)

Comment: @jsexpert I have updated the post with .git/config file of the affected repo

Comment: Looks like your config is fine. can you please try and run git flow init (add -f if needed) to the new cloned repo and then checkout develop again?

Comment: I will install git flow but I am not using git flow, is there anything that git flow will do specifically for this branch ? and bigger question is why is it auto-tracking without git flow init on the other repository